# Is there a conditional subjunctive?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, usage, temps-grammatical

Is there a conditional subjunctive?

For example, what sort of subjunctive should one use for:

J’attendrais jusqu’à ce qu’il me répondrait ?

Or does one use the présent after the subjunctive?

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing as combining two moods in a single verb. At best, you've got one mood for the principal verb and another for the subordinate. In your example it would be "J'attendrais (cond.) jusqu'à ce qu'il me *réponde* (subj.)".

Answer (score 5):

We use subjonctive after « jusqu'à ». For example :

- Présent

  > J'attends jusqu'à ce qu'il me réponde.
- Passé

  > J'attendais jusqu'à ce qu'il m'ait répondu.
- Futur : There is no such thing as « subjonctif futur » in french. So, after future, we use « subjonctive présent »

  > J'attendrai jusqu'à ce qu'il me réponde.
- **Conditionnal : we still use subjonctive after conditionnal**

  > Si je n'étais pas pressé, j'attendrais jusqu'à ce qu'il me **réponde**.